# Relational Proof

Tags: proof-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

I'm having trouble understanding the concepts of relational proofs. I understand the definition on relation, but I'm having trouble understanding the proof process of the reflexive, symmetric, and transitive properties.
Check if the relation R is a equivalence relation.

$ R = \{(x,x): x \in Z\}$

Proof: Let $a\in Z$. then $ \forall a, \exists a : a = a$ Therefore $(a,a) \in R$ since R is all possible ordered pairs with the same entry, 
so R is reflexive.

Proof: Let $b,c\in Z$. Then $\forall (b,c) \in Z^2, \exists (c,b) \in Z^2$. Also since $(a,b) \in R$ when a=b, then $(b,a) \in R $ when b=a, therefore aRb $\implies$ bRa. Also So since 
∀b,c∈Z,(b,c)∉R
∀b,c∈Z,(b,c)∉R
where b!=c so the antecedent of the implication will be false, therefore the implication will be true. Which covers all cases for a,b
$\therefore$ R is symmetric.

Does this look correct for the symmetric proof. I feel really uncertain about it. 
Note: I left out the transitive proof bc I want to understand the other parts before I try that. 
Thank you.

Comment: If that is how your relation is defined, then I would say that R is reflexive BY DEFINITION of R. There’s nothing to prove. But for symmetric, you want to show that $\forall b,c \in \mathbb{Z}, (b,c) \in R$ implies $(c,b) \in R$. For transitivity, show that $\forall b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}, (b,c) \in R$ AND $ (c,d) \in R$ implies $(b,d) \in R$.  HINT: for your relation, $(b,c) \in R$ if and only if $b=c$

Comment: Is this correct logic:So since $\forall b,c \in Z, (b,c) \notin R$ where b!=c so the antecedent of the implication will be false, therefore the implication will be true. Which covers all cases for a,b.

Comment: @AaronVanRossum That is not correct, because the definition of symmetry allows $b=c$. Instead, start by supposing $(b,c) \in R$. Then, since every element of $R$ is of the form $(x,x)$ for some $x \in Z$, you must have $(b,c)=(x,x)$ for some $x \in Z$. Can you continue from here to show $(c,b) \in R$?

Comment: Yeah but didn't I prove that correct in the original post?

Comment: No you did not, you started with $b,c \in \Bbb Z$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more precise and more direct in your symmetry proof:

Start by picking an arbitrary $(a,b) \in R$. This means by definition that $(a,b)=(x,x)$ for some $x \in \Bbb Z$. Ergo $a=x$ and $b=x$ and so $a=b$ and then $(b,a)=(x,x) \in R$ as well, and you're done. (For an arbitrary $(a,b) \in R$ we have shown that also $(b,a) \in R$.)

Comment: Ok now its clicking.

Comment: To put it concisely: By definition of $R$, we have $\forall a\in Z~.\forall b\in Z~.(\langle a,b\rangle\in R\leftrightarrow(a=b))$.  So since $\forall a\in Z~.(a=a)$ and $\forall a\in Z~.\forall b\in Z~.(a=b\to b=a)$ , the relation is reflexive and symmetric.  You can now check for transitivity.